# Did redhat 6.5 recently break scipy?

Tags: scipy, redhat

I have a program I've been working on for ages. I haven't updated it since May 12th. When I run it today I get errors:

```
gsh@localhost 2014-05-08]$ ./kaplan.py
/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/numpy/oldnumeric/__init__.py:11: ModuleDeprecationWarning: The oldnumeric module will be dropped in Numpy 1.9
  warnings.warn(_msg, ModuleDeprecationWarning)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./kaplan.py", line 6, in <module>
    from scipy import interpolate, constants
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/scipy/interpolate/__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from polyint import *
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/scipy/interpolate/polyint.py", line 2, in <module>
    from scipy import factorial
ImportError: cannot import name factorial
```

I'm running Redhat 6.5 workstation. I think redhat broke scipy sometime between May 12th and now. Does it look like I am correct, or is something else perhaps wrong?

Comment: I can 'fix' it via editing /usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/scipy/interpolate/polyint.py and making the code read  `from scipy.misc import factorial` but that may not be the correct fix.

Comment: And basemap seems broken

Comment: While I cannot comment on what's going on with Redhat 6.5, I notice that your fix in `polyint` is actually in scipy since at least 2010: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/maintenance/0.8.x/scipy/interpolate/polyint.py#L2